# Trick rescaling with plyr (ddply) in R

Tags: r, plyr

I've got this csv table for which I need to rescale data between 0 and 1 per each column. That is, the lowest value of any given column will be 0, the highest will be 1, and all other values will be linearly scaled accordingly. Here's my script:

```
tableau  <- read.csv(text="Net,B,C,D,E (e),F (f)
a,1.88,0.15,0.6,10,90
b,2.05,0.23,0.51,55,80
c,2.09,0.29,0.4,58,88
d,2.07,0.52,0.36,80,84
e,2.13,0.3,0.27,7,90")
tableau.m <- melt(tableau)
tableau.m <- ddply(tableau.m, .(variable), transform,rescale = rescale(value))
```

The issue is that the 1st paragraph is not totally true: the rescales should be done by column, except for the two last columns: I need "E.e" and "F.f" to be rescaled together according to the lowest value of the two columns, and the highest value of the two columns. That is, for these columns only and not for the others, the lowest value should be 7 (showing as white), and the highest should be 90 (showing as dark blue).

So, in column F.f, all cells should be shown as a dark-ish blue.

Is it possible to achieve this with *plyr*?

[image]

(In this example, column B should read with 2.13 being white, 1.88 being dark blue, and 2.07's, 2.09's, 2.05's shades being scaled accordingly. The other column should be left untouched.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `ifelse` statement to scale the `E.e` and `F.f` values based on their combined range, rather than the range of each individual group of values:

```
tableau.m = ddply(tableau.m, .(variable), transform,
                  rescale = ifelse(variable %in% c("E.e","F.f"), 
                                   rescale(value,
                                           from=range(value[variable %in% c("E.e","F.f")])),
                                   rescale(value)))
```

**UPDATE:** After seeing your comment, I realized that my original code was incorrect. We've asked `plyr` to group by `variable`, so it can't look at two separate values of `variable` at the same time to get the correct range for `rescale`.

Here's updated code that gets the correct range from the full data frame. It works, but it does so by going "outside" the environment of plyr's grouping function, which doesn't seem very elegant to me (and perhaps might even have unintended consequences in some situations).

```
tableau.m = ddply(tableau.m, .(variable), transform,
                  rescale=ifelse(variable %in% c("E.e","F.f"), 
                                 rescale(value,
                                         from=range(tableau.m$value[tableau.m$variable %in% c("E.e","F.f")])),
                                 rescale(value)))
```

Comment: Thanks eipi10! It's strange though, it doesn't seem to work on my side. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes. Works for me. What result are you getting? Is it an issue of using `E.e F.f` vs. `E..e. F..f.` in your data frame? I got rid of the extra periods in my version of the data frame, since you were calling them `E.e` and `F.f` in your question, but the extra periods are still there in your code.

Comment: I'm getting this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xoatbfgfnatypo/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202015-05-27%2011.01.40.png?dl=0
For instance, line 19 shouldn't be 1, and line 22 shouldn't be 0.

Comment: I'm wondering if I should ask another question: is it possible to combine several ifelse requests if I also need to select other columns as such: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/646107c1fb5694eb7f68 ?

Comment: You can nest `ifelse` to deal with multiple options, but you might find it easier to use the [`switch` function](http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/scripting.html#switch-statement).

Comment: Alright, I tried a few ways with no success, I'll post another question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I realize you asked for a `plyr` answer but here's a `dplyr` one for others who come looking:

```
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(tidyr)

tableau %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(rescale), B, C, D) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(rescale(., from=range(tableau[,5:6]))), 5, 6) %>% 
  gather(variable, rescale, -Net) %>% 
  left_join(gather(tableau, variable, value))
```